# How to delete rows using Office Scripts based on dynamic column range in Excel?

Tags: excel, delete-row, office-scripts, ms-office-script

I am working on a task in Excel using Office Scripts and I'm facing an issue with deleting rows based on a dynamic column range. Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

I want to delete entire rows below the used range in column A.
The column range is dynamic and is determined by the data in column A.

Ex: Below excel after row no 10 there is no data in A column so what I want is to delete rows after 10th row. Column range is dynamic.

[image]

Output I'm expecting;
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try.

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    let table = selectedSheet.getTables()[0];
    if (table) {
        let lastCell: ExcelScript.Range = table.getRange().getColumn(0).getLastCell();
        if(! lastCell.getText()){
            let lastRow = lastCell.getRangeEdge(ExcelScript.KeyboardDirection.up);
            selectedSheet.getRange(`${lastRow.getRowIndex() + 2}:${lastCell.getRowIndex() + 1}`)
                .delete(ExcelScript.DeleteShiftDirection.up);
        }
    }
}
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [ExcelScript.Range interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/excelscript/excelscript.range?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&view=office-scripts#excelscript-excelscript-range-getlastcell-member(1))